# Как в моб. версии Bootstrap сделать так, чтобы при открытии Navbar вложенные Dropdown уже были раскрыты?

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap, адаптивная-верстка

Вот верхний Navbar, в нем есть Dropdown меню: http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar

На широком экране Navbar развернут, а Dropdown свернут, как и должно быть.

А на узкой мобильной Navbar сворачивается и при клике по кнопке меню, открывается, но Dropdown свернут, а я хотел бы, чтобы при клике открывался и сам развернутый Navbar и Dropdown тоже отображался раскрытым, и стрелку рядом с Dropdown можно также убрать. Что-то как ни пытался, так и не получилось без JS на одном CSS.

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/ybmtmok1/1/)

```css
@import url('https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css');

@media only screen and (max-width:480px){
  .dropdown-menu{
    display: block;
    position: static;
    background-color:transparent;
    border:0 none;
    box-shadow:none;
    margin-top:0;
    position:static;
    width:100%;
  }
  .navbar-nav .dropdown-menu > li > a, 
  .navbar-nav .dropdown-menu .dropdown-header {
    padding:5px 15px 5px 25px;
  }
  .navbar-nav .dropdown-menu > li > a{
    line-height:20px;
  }
  .navbar-default .navbar-nav .dropdown-menu > li > a{

    color:#777;
  }
  a.dropdown-toggle .caret {
    display: none;
  }   
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: [Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы раскрыть выпадающий список, Бутстрап добавляет класс `.open` к элементу меню с этим списком. Поэтому ищем всё, что [bootstrap.css](https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.css) говорит про `.open` и `.dropdown-menu` при ширине экрана до `767px`. Получается много всего – и про форму, и про цвет, и про видимость.

Удаляем из найденных инструкций `.open`, чтобы действовали сразу. Добавляем, где нужно, `.navbar-nav`, чтобы открыть выпадающие списки только внутри меню. И заворачиваем всё в `@media (max-width: 767px)`.

В этом же медиа-запросе прячем чёрный треугольничек у переключателя.

Проверьте: https://jsfiddle.net/glebkema/eL7eLq4L/

```css
@import url('https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css');

@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .navbar-nav .dropdown-toggle .caret {
    display: none;
  }
  
  .navbar-nav .dropdown-menu {
    display: block;
  }
  .navbar-nav .dropdown > a {
    outline: 0;
  }

  .navbar-nav .dropdown-menu {
    position: static;
    float: none;
    width: auto;
    margin-top: 0;
    background-color: transparent;
    border: 0;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
            box-shadow: none;
  }
  .navbar-nav .dropdown-menu > li > a,
  .navbar-nav .dropdown-menu .dropdown-header {
    padding: 5px 15px 5px 25px;
  }
  .navbar-nav .dropdown-menu > li > a {
    line-height: 20px;
  }
  .navbar-nav .dropdown-menu > li > a:hover,
  .navbar-nav .dropdown-menu > li > a:focus {
    background-image: none;
  }

  .navbar-default .navbar-nav > > a,
  .navbar-default .navbar-nav > > a:hover,
  .navbar-default .navbar-nav > > a:focus {
    color: #555;
    background-color: #e7e7e7;
  }
  .navbar-default .navbar-nav .dropdown-menu > li > a {
    color: #777;
  }
  .navbar-default .navbar-nav .dropdown-menu > li > a:hover,
  .navbar-default .navbar-nav .dropdown-menu > li > a:focus {
    color: #333;
    background-color: transparent;
  }
  .navbar-default .navbar-nav .dropdown-menu > .active > a,
  .navbar-default .navbar-nav .dropdown-menu > .active > a:hover,
  .navbar-default .navbar-nav .dropdown-menu > .active > a:focus {
    color: #555;
    background-color: #e7e7e7;
  }
  .navbar-default .navbar-nav .dropdown-menu > .disabled > a,
  .navbar-default .navbar-nav .dropdown-menu > .disabled > a:hover,
  .navbar-default .navbar-nav .dropdown-menu > .disabled > a:focus {
    color: #ccc;
    background-color: transparent;
  }
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Всё работает отлично. Огромное спасибо за подробное объяснение, как найти нужные css классы, а не просто готовый код. До этого я думал, что есть какой-то класс (например .open-xs) добавив который меню будет раскрыто на нужном разрешении, значит нет, но решение есть. Спасибо. Плюс пока что поставить не могу из-за недостающего рейтинга.

Comment: Рад помочь. Спасибо за комментарий, что именно помогло. А рейтинг - дело наживное :)